# How can I automatically let Matlab input the file in sequence?

Tags: matlab, iteration

How can I let Matlab automatically input the file itself rather than one by one myself?

I mean, I want to put `Sample 1.wav` and then output `Sample 1.png` and then
put `Sample 2.wav` and then output `Sample 2.png` and then put `Sample 3.wav` and then output `Sample 3.png`

I do not want to type myself 1, 2, 3 and rather let the matlab run itself from `1 to 1,000`

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('sample1.wav');
spectrogram(y,'yaxis')
saveas(gcf,'sample1.png')
```

Then

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('sample2.wav');
spectrogram(y,'yaxis')
saveas(gcf,'sample2.png')
```

Then

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('sample3.wav');
spectrogram(y,'yaxis')
saveas(gcf,'sample3.png')
```

Comment: can try iteration

Answer (score 4):

To programmatically iterate through files, use the `dir` command to get a list of all files in a directory. [Documentation for dir](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html)

For example, you can get a list of files in the current directory with the command:

```
list = dir
```

```
list = 

  4×1 struct array with fields:

    name
    folder
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

In this case, I have 2 files in the current directory, with the addition of 2 inodes (`'.'` and `'..'`). These are all stored in a struct array called `list`. You can see the list of files by the command:

```
{list.name}
```

```
ans =

  1×4 cell array

    {'.'}    {'..'}    {'fileA.m'}    {'fileB.m'}
```

---

Filenames can be generated programmatically with `sprintf()`. [Documentation for sprintf](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

```
for i = 1:10
    sprintf("sample%d.png", i)
end
```

```
ans = 

    "sample1.png"
ans = 

    "sample2.png"
ans = 

    "sample3.png"
...
```

---

Combine the two together, and you can iterate through all of the files in the list with a code like so:

```
list = dir; % Get files in current directory
fileList = {list.name}; % Store filenames in a cell array
fileList(1:2) = []; % Delete the inodes '.' and '..'

for i = 1:length(fileList)
    % Get current filename, use curly brackets to extract string from cell array
    currentFile = fileList{i}; 
    
    % Use sprintf() to automatically generate filenames
    saveName = sprintf("sample%d.png", i); 

    % Your code goes here
    [y,Fs] = audioread(currentFile);
    spectrogram(y,'yaxis')
    saveas(gcf,saveName)
end
```

---

If moving to the directory of the target files is inconvenient, you can give the `dir` command a target directory: `list = dir('C:/TargetDirectory/')`. This will give you the list of files in that directory, but note that you will have to add that target directory to the MATLAB path, or explicitly add that to the target filename when loading. E.g.:

```
% Directory path, use double quotes, not single quotes
targetDirectory = "C:/TargetDirectory/";

currentFile = fileList{i};
currentFile = targetDirectory + currentFile; % Append path to file

% Do stuff
load(currentFile)
```